How do I a gap and island analysis with a power query?
I have a dataset similar to the one below, and I am trying to do a gap and island analysis on it.



Item
TransDate
InventoryCount
explanation




Bicycle
01/01/2023
0
First time the item Bicycle has been insert in database, this record should be disregarded for the calculation


Bicycle
01/02/2023
15
Bicycle first stock arrival


Bicycle
01/05/2023
10
Bicycle stock partially depleted


Bicycle
01/07/2023
0
Bicycle stock completely depleted


Bicycle
01/31/2023
15
Bicycle second stock arrival


Car
01/01/2023
0
First time the item Car has been insert in database, this record should be disregarded for the calculation


Car
01/20/2023
3
Car first stock arrival


Car
01/21/2023
0
Car first stock depleted


Car
01/25/2023
5
Car second stock arrival


Car
01/26/2023
0
Car second stock depleted


Car
02/10/2023
2
Car third stock arrival


Motorcycle
01/01/2023
0
First time the item Motorcycle has been insert in database, this record should be disregarded for the calculation


Motorcycle
01/02/2023
10
Motorcycle first stock arrival


Motorcycle
01/05/2023
5
Motorcycle stock partially depleted


Motorcycle
01/08/2023
0
Motorcycle first stock completely depleted


Motorcycle
01/28/2023
15
Motorcycle second stock arrival



What I am trying to do, in power query, is to find the number of out of stock times and the length (in days) of the out of stock situation something like:
Bicycle 1 time out of stock for 25 days.
Car 2 times out of stock for 4 and 15 days.
Motorcycle 1 time out of stock for 20 days.
There is not much online about gap and island analysis in power query and the only thing I found does not really help. I've been able to figure out something via SQL, but I have no access to the original source.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You can follow an approach similar to this in Power Query.

Sort by TransDate
GroupBy Item
Then in the nested Grouped table:

Remove top rows that are InventoryCount = 0
Add new column for NextDate if InventoryCount > 0
Fill-up the NextDate
Remove duplicates on InventoryCount & NextDate - this remove consecutive 0
Calculate days by subtracting TransDate from NextDate
Filter on Days is greater than 0
Expand table with the needed columns



let
    Source = YourTable,
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"TransDate", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Item"}, {{"Rows", each _, type table [Item=nullable text, TransDate=nullable date, InventoryCount=nullable number]}}),
    #"RemoveTop0Rows" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", { "Rows", each Table.Skip(_, each [InventoryCount] = 0) }),
    #"Add NextDate" = Table.TransformColumns(#"RemoveTop0Rows", { "Rows", each Table.AddColumn(_, "NextDate", each if [InventoryCount] > 0 then [TransDate] else null) }),
    #"FillUp NextDate" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Add NextDate", { "Rows", each Table.FillUp(_ ,{"NextDate"}) }),
    #"Remove Consecutive zeros" = Table.TransformColumns(#"FillUp NextDate", { "Rows", each Table.Distinct(_, {"NextDate", "InventoryCount"}) }),
    #"Add days" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Remove Consecutive zeros", { "Rows", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Days", each Duration.Days([NextDate] - [TransDate]), Int64.Type) }),
    #"Filter Days" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Add days", { "Rows", each Table.SelectRows(_, each [Days] > 0) }),
    #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filter Days", "Rows", {"Days"}, {"Days"})
in
    #"Expanded Rows"

To give you a resulting table similar to:


Thank so much Sam, this work extremely well. I only have one problem with this as sometimes there are multiple entries at zero value of inventorycount before the first entry with a positive value. Do you have any idea of how I can bypass the problem?

Sure thing, updated answer above. Table.Skip(_, 1) updated to Table.Skip(_, each [InventoryCount] = 0)

Once again thank you so much Sam. It works like a charm and I am extremely thankful for your precious help.
Time for me to study to understand in deep what you just did!!!

Hi Sam, the solution provided works well in most of the conditions. I did a few test on different dataset and apparently, if there are consecutive 0 values (like the case below) the calculation does not work.
If there are not multiple zero occurrences your solution works perfectly
Item TransDate InventoryCount
Car 01/01/2023 0
Car 01/18/2023 3
Car 01/19/2023 0
Car 01/20/2023 0
Car 01/21/2023 0
Car 01/25/2023 5
Car 01/26/2023 0
Car 02/10/2023 2

Updated answer above. See new step 3.4 to remove consecutive 0s.

Works like a charm. thank you so much, Sam!

can we use DAX to get this output?
Column =
VAR _last =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Item] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Item] )
                && 'Table'[TransDate] < EARLIER ( 'Table'[TransDate] )
        ),
        'Table'[TransDate]
    )
VAR _lastinventory =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Item] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Item] )
                && 'Table'[TransDate] = _last
        ),
        'Table'[InventoryCount]
    )
VAR _lastex =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Item] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Item] )
                && 'Table'[TransDate] = _last
        ),
        'Table'[explanation]
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        _lastinventory = 0
            && CONTAINSSTRING ( _lastex, "depleted" ),
        DATEDIFF ( _last, 'Table'[TransDate], DAY )
    )



Well, can we? Answers are not the place for questions.

Thank you Ryan, really appreciated. I will take a look at this solution as well!
